# Quantization of CNNs : Choosing Ranges

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

To quantize a model so that it's weighted (and/or activation) is in integers 8 bit instead of floating point 32 bit for faster calculation, we need to choose a range in the weights.

Is there any way this range selection can be done optimally instead of hit and trial?

For example, let's say we have a weight distribution(floating point 32) in [100.0,500.0], we choose the range [200.0,455.0] and map it to (integer 8) [0,255] such that 200.0 is mapped to 0 and 455.0 is mapped to 255 and all the intermediate weights are mapped linearly to integers (closest).

*Here a range ([200.0,455.0]) was chosen randomly which leaves weights in [100.0,200.0) and (455.0,500.0] also if our range was too large compared to 256, it would lead to clustering of weights in the mappings.*

**Quantization is done at the cost of accuracy and an optimum range-selection can help in reducing this cost.**

Comment: This is a research level question. Go find a publication that says how to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's solely about ML models.

Comment: I could not find a suitable publication if anybody finds anything please share

Comment: Request for external resource is also off topic.